# Remove white background from overlapping matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm making a timeseries plot of three variables with three subplots using `fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1)`, which currently looks like this:

[image]

I've put the subplots right next to each other using `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)` and made the splines in between transparent, but would like the subplots to be closer still (so that the y axes overlap a little and the datapoints are closer together vertically). If the white backgrounds of the subplots were transparent, I think this could be achieved by using `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-0.1)`. Doing this makes the y-axes ticks and labels overlap nicely, but unfortunately the white backgrounds of the lower two subplots obscure the datapoints in the subplots above. This is noticeable in the top timeseries of the plot below:

[image]

Can anybody suggest a fix for this or another approach to get the y axes to overlap a bit and make the three timeseries a bit tighter in the vertical axis?

Comment: Use `ax.set_facecolor('none')`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! If you submit it as an answer I'll select it?